# Flash debug player installation problem

Tags: 11.10, firefox, flash, browser

Standard Version:

When I download the player without the debugger [from here](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/completion/?installer=Flash_Player_11_for_other_Linux_%28.tar.gz%29_64-bit) and place the `libflashplayer.so` file into the `~/.mozzila/plugins/` directory the player works fine.

Debugger version:
But when I download the plugin from:
http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html 
(Download the Linux Flash Player 11.1 Plugin content debugger (TAR.GZ, 6.86MB))
The player is not working.

I need to know how to install the debugger version.

System info:

```
Linux mashine 3.0.0-15-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 20 17:23:00 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Browser info:

```
/usr/lib/firefox-9.0.1/firefox: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, stripped
```

EDIT:
I set up a virtual mashine with ubuntu 11.10 32bit version and the flash player with debugger works fine.
So it's a problem related to the 64 bit version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From that link you showed us, it seems that those debuggers are only 32 bit binaries.
`Adobe Flash Player 11.1 — 32 bit Debugger (aka debug players or content debuggers) and Standalone (aka Projectors) Players for Flex and Flash developers`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the debugger version which 32-bit only you will need `nspluginwrapper`. In a terminal enter these commands but first make sure a version  of adobe flash is not installed on your computer

```
wget -O ~/Downloads/flash-debugger.tar.gz http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/11/flashplayer_11_plugin_debug.i386.tar.gz 
sudo tar zxfv ~/Downloads/flash-debugger.tar.gz -C /
sudo mv libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins
nspluginwrapper -v -a -i
```

Otherwise just install 64-bit flash without debug

```
sudo apt-get install adobe-flashplugin
```

Comment: If you get errors about a missing libssl then install ia32-libs. I found that out the hard way. :P

Comment: THANK YOU!  I spent several frustrating hours on this answer... it is now working.  +100 if I could.